# How to -find -exec cp files from a list containing a portion of the filename

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find, xargs

I've been searching for a long time and can't find an answer that works. I have a list with partial filenames (the first few letters of the filenames). If I place the file names individually as follows it works:

```
find ~/directory/to/search -name "filename*" -print -exec cp '{}' ~/directory/to/copyto \;
```

If I try to include the list in this scenario it does not:

```
cat ~/directory/List.txt | while read line 
do 
echo "Text read from file - $line" 
find ~/directory/to/search -name "$line*" -type f
done
```

neither does this:

```
cat ~/directory/List.txt | while read line 
do 
echo "Text read from file - $line" 
find ~/directory/to/search -name "$line&*" -type f
done
```

Ultimately, I'd like to add:

```
-exec cp '{}' ~/directory/to/copy/to \;
```

And copy over all files matching the find criteria.

I've tried using grep but the files are huge so it would take forever. I tried using all sorts of combinations of find, xargs, cp, grep and regex as read in previous searches and no luck.

Is the only solution to write a long script with a bunch of if then statements? I've been using Linux but it would be cool to use it on mac as well.

Comment: What's the output of your attempts, and what are the filenames you're looking for?

Comment: I can't replicate this. `while read name; do find . -name "$name*"; done <<<foo
` works as expected, finding `foo.txt`.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is the worst possible problem description. "Hey mechanic my car doesn't work - here's a photo of it, now tell me what's wrong with it". Tell us in what way it "doesn't work" - wrong output, no output, error messages, core dumps, something else?

Comment: @Jon it seems what you tried is similar to my first attempt above.I tried using:  `while read line; do find . -name "$line&*" \; ; done < ~/data/Studies/EST/ESTlist.txt` but came across a: `find: paths must precede expression:` error.

Comment: @RLz Ah, that is because of the `\;`, which isn't needed (it is the terminator for the `-exec` option). Take that out and you might be good. Also, should that `$line&*` just be `$line*`? The `&` isn't needed to concatenate in Bash.

Comment: @Jon I tried `while read line; do echo "Looking for $line"; find ~/data/Raw -name "$line*" ; < cat ~/data/Studies/EST/ESTlist.txt \; ; done` both with and without the & and while it does read the file as evident by echo it does not return the find results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude attempt at getting away with a single `find` invocation.

```
predicates=()
or=''
while read -r line; do
    predicates+=($or -name "$line*")
    or="-o"
done < ~/directory/list.txt
find ~/directory/to/search -type f \( "${predicates[@]}" \) \
    -exec cp -t ~/directory/to/copy/to {} +
```

The array functionality requires an extended shell (Bash, `ksh`, etc) with this functionality; it won't work with `/bin/sh`.

`cp -t` is a GNU extension; if you don't have that, maybe just use your original `-exec cp {} dir \;` though it will be less efficient. Some old versions of `find` also don't support `-exec ... +`.

Comment: You might want to rwn this with `cp -v` while testing so you can see what it's doing.